# compare two array of objects javascript and throw the unmatched array elements into new array using underscore or lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays `apple = [1,5,10,15,20]`, `bottle = [1,5,10,15,20,25]` using lodash or any javascript function, I want an array c with unique elements `c= [25]`. To be more precise, I want the list of all the elements when 'apple' array is compared with 'bottle' array, to display the elements which are unique/

Comment: [`var c = _.difference(bottle, apple);`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function with `reduce()` and `filter()` for this.

```js
var apple = [1,5,10,15,20], bottle = [1,5,10,15,20,25] 

function diff(a1, a2) {
  //Concat array2 to array1 to create one array, and then use reduce on that array to return
  //one object as result where key is element and value is number of occurrences of that element
  var obj = a1.concat(a2).reduce(function(result, element) {
    result[element] = (result[element] || 0) + 1
    return result
  }, {})
  
  //Then as function result return keys from previous object where value is == 1 which means that
  // that element is unique in both arrays.
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(element) {
    return obj[element] == 1
  })
}

console.log(diff(apple, bottle))
```

Shorter version of same code with ES6 arrow functions.

```js
var apple = [1,5,10,15,20], bottle = [1,5,10,15,20,25] 

function diff(a1, a2) {
  var obj = a1.concat(a2).reduce((r, e) => (r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1, r), {})
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(e => obj[e] == 1)
}

console.log(diff(apple, bottle))
```

Comment: Probably want to write a little more self-documenting code..

Comment: @mhodges I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the opposite array.

This proposal uses a [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) function which returns `true` if the element a is not in the set b.

For a symmetric difference, the filtering with callback has to be used for both sides.

```js
function getComplement(collection) {
    // initialize and close over a set created from the collection passed in
    var set = new Set(collection);
    // return iterator callback for .filter()
    return function (item) {
        return !set.has(item);
    };
}
var apple = [1,5,10,15,20], 
    bottle = [1,5,10,15,20,25],
    unique = [
        ...apple.filter(getComplement(bottle)),
        ...bottle.filter(getComplement(apple))
    ];

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: You normally write very clear and concise answers, but I have to say, even as an experienced ES6 developer, your use of arrow functions and single-letter variable names here is cryptic and very hard to read. Just because ES6 gave us the arrow function, doesn't mean we have to use it to cram code onto a single line.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the function keyword?

Comment: @mhodges, no, function is good. but what do you mean with the question?

Comment: `complement = b => (s => a => !s.has(a))(new Set(b))` reads like it belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ I know what it does, but I guarantee > 80% of people required to write JS for their job would have a tough time deciphering exactly what's going on - god forbid that code ever gets a bug in it or needs to be changed

Comment: @mhodges, feel free to add in an edit the style, you find best.

Comment: Okay, I updated it