# Comparing one array with another and push uncommon values to new array using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an nested array(procdata):

> [[2017-02-14",null,23.0,"Doc","T1632","2
>   Bitewings",290]],[["2017-03-01",null,10.0,"Doc","T1254","Fluoride",289],["2017-03-01",null,40.0,"Doc","T1632","4
>   Bitewings",288]]

and another array(paySplitdata) as below :

> [[290]]

Code I tried :

```
var a = [], diff = [];
for (var i = 0; i < procdata.length; i++) {
    a[procdata[i][6]] = true;
}

for (var i = 0; i < paySplitdata.length; i++) {
    if (a[paySplitdata[i]]) {
        delete a[paySplitdata[i]];
    } else {
        a[paySplitdata[i]] = true;
    }
}

for (var k in a) {
    diff.push(k);
}
alert(diff);
```

I am getting array(diff) :

> [[289],[288]]

but i am expecting new array after filtering index[6] as below:

> [["2017-03-01",null,10.0,"Doc","T1254","Fluoride",289]],
>   [["2017-03-01",null,40.0,"Doc","T1632","4Bitewings",288]]

Comment: which version of ng are you using?

Comment: are the arrays going in like thus => [a, b] and you want a flattened array where [a[i], b[i]] is returned

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question does not shows any sign of effort.

Comment: no, its nested array

Comment: Can you show us the work you've done so far, what methods you've tried but haven't worked? Doesn't a library method (like Ramda/Lodash) like _.difference() work, for example?

Comment: you might have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42496158/1447675

Comment: Now, I updated my question, Please go through it and help.@Rajesh & @rrd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for looking if the number is in the array `paySplitdata`.

The result is an array with items which does not contain the numbers of `paySplitdata`.

```js
var procdata = [["2017-02-14", null, 23.0, "Doc", "T1632", "2 Bitewings", 290], ["2017-03-01", null, 10.0, "Doc", "T1254", "Fluoride", 289], ["2017-03-01", null, 40.0, "Doc", "T1632", "4 Bitewings", 288]],
    paySplitdata = [290],
    diff = procdata.filter(function (a) {
        return paySplitdata.indexOf(a[6]) === -1;
    });

console.log(diff);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding question and upvote it and also for perfect answer..!!